# Python Nose html report how to run from a batch file

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, nose

In windows cmd prompt I can run the following command to run my Selenium regression script using Nose to generate the html report.
I am having trouble running the command from a batch file.
The bat file seems to open, a cmd prompt opens but it hten just stays stuck there.

The command in my bat file is:

```
set TEST_HOME=%~dp0
cd %~dp0    
c:\Python27\Scripts\nosetests.exe "E:\test_runners\selenium_regression_test_5_1_1\ClearCore - Regression Test\Regression_TestCase\RegressionProject_TestCase2.py" --with-html --html-file="E:\test_runners\selenium_regression_test_5_1_1\ClearCore - Regression Test\TestReport\TestReport_%date.html"
```

The bat file is in the test-runners directory.
The bat file is called run_test - copy.bat

Can anyone help?  How can i get the nose html report command to work fro the  bat file?

Thanks, Riaz

Comment: This batch file is working now.  I restarted the server and it is working now.